# Docker: можно ли контейнер, созданный из Windows разместить на Linux?

Tags: c#, администрирование, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

У нас стартап и мы все еще активно пополняемся единомышленниками, но наш продукт уже в скором времени близится к пилотному запуску. ПО наше состоит из следующих модулей:

1. API — проект ASP.NET Core Web API 2
2. MySQL
3. Web-клиент — приложение на Angular 5. *Мы не скрестили ASP.NET Core и
   Angular, а разрабатываем веб-клиент Angular отдельно с Node.js на борту.*

Стоит задача, организовать стратегию менее безболезненного развертывания всех трех узлов на инфраструктуре клиента, естественно с учетом того что будет написан туториал по инсталяции и что установкой будет заниматься техническая служба клиента.

Операционная система, которая будет крутиться на сервере клиента неизвестна и хотелось сделать некий универсальный процесс инсталяции который подходил бы как на Windows так и для Linux. *Понятное дело, что за универсальность надо платить.*

Как писал выше, мы только развивающийся отряд, и мы не имеем пока еще в арсенале хорошего специалиста-администратора с большим опытом решения подобных задач по развертыванию.

**Docker**. Докер, Docker и еще раз Докер. Естественно в первую очередь программисту приходит в голову это ПО одной из задач *(я сказал одной из)* которого является избавить программиста от проблем развертывания и дать максимально сфокусироваться на кодинге. *Ох если бы это было так.*

**Прокси-сервер**. И как не крути, но плюс к Kestrel/HTTP.sys какой-то из серверов Apache, IIS, nginx и т.д. все же нужен *на сколько понял я*. Даже если клиент планирует работать с нашим продуктом только внутри корпоративной сети. 
Дела с HTTP.sys конечно лучше: он не такой голый как Kestrel, *но у нас то речь об универсальности*, а HTTP.sys только для Windows.
Пытался к примеру установить nginx на Windows Server в качестве эксперимента: мама родная, со стороны казалось, что я в первый раз вижу компьютер).

---

И если можно я задал бы два вопроса:

1) Первый вопрос он более общий, вы наверное догадались: что посоветуете?

2) А теперь, чтобы конкретизироваться: я сейчас работаю на Windows 10 и если я задумал использовать Docker, то я ведь правильно понимаю, что мне надо создать четыре контейнера

1. Контейнер с прокси-сервером (Apache, nginx или IIS)
2. Контейнер с СУБД MySQL
3. Контейнер с Angular-приложением
4. Контейнер с проектом ASP.NET Core 2 Web API

Можно ли это сделать прямо из Windows? То есть будет ли работать контейнер созданный на Windows-машине на Linux?

Comment: Да, можно создавать docker-контейнеры в Windows, а потом размещать их в Linux.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну а в общем, я в правильном направлении иду, как ты думаешь?

Comment: Думаю, в правильном. У нас сервисы на .NET Core и Java с помощью Docker хостятся на Amazon Web Services. Всё работает прекрасно. Разработчики могут работать на любой ОС.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, меня что еще смущает, так это: когда в VS создаешь проект, то там есть чек-бокс `Enable Docker Support` и при его выборе появляется выпадающий список с выбор одного из двух { `Windows`, `Linux` }. [Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker#new-app) пишут что это `Container type`. Какая разница между контейнером типа Windows и контейнером типа Linux?

Comment: Если вы выбрали nginx, и mysql, то работать они естественно будут под linux, и контейнер у вас будет линукствый, вы его можете создать под виндой, но он будет линуксовый и в винде будет как виртуалка, т.е. профита ноль, только для dev, так что ни о какой универсальности речи не идёт. Вам в любом случае понадобится linux, или linux и windows (для iis) сервера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker под Windows может работать в двух режимах - Windows Containers и Linux Containers. Режимы переключаются через иконку в трее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В режиме Windows Containers он собирает и хостит контейнеры прямо в текущей операционке. Собранные в этом режиме контейнеры нельзя разместить под Linux.

В режиме Linux Containers он на самом деле собирает и запускает контейнеры на линуксовой виртуалке - она видна в Hyper-V Manager. Собранные в этом режиме контейнеры можно разместить под Linux.

Под каждый рантайм есть свой набор тэгов -
 все доступные можно посмотреть на https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/

Т.е. да, вы можете включить режим Linux Containers, собрать набор из 4-х контейнеров (взяв nginx в качестве прокси), и потом запустить все это под Linux.

Comment: Видя многоточие в конце, ожидал, что появится окно с вариантами выбора. А оно сразу переключило тип контейнеров. Фигово сделано.